# Phasor angle calculation

Tags: analysis, phasor

In this example, for Vo it first says it is lagging by -134.8 degrees, however when then calculating actual Iin, the angle for Vo becomes -138.4.

I'm wondering if -134.8 is a typo, and if it isn't; how did they get that number?

[image: ?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the angle of the output voltage can be found using the voltage divider formula:

$$\varphi=\arg\left(\frac{4\text{||}\left(-2\text{j}\right)}{2+12\text{j}+\left(4\text{||}\left(-2\text{j}\right)\right)}\right)=\arg\left(-\frac{18}{145}-\frac{16}{145}\cdot\text{j}\right)=$$
$$\arctan\left(\frac{8}{9}\right)-\pi\approx-2.41495\space\text{rad}\tag1$$

which is equal to approximately: \$-138.366^\circ\$.